# How do I merge multiple dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 3 dataFrames and all 3 have different columns. How do I make 1 big dataFrame of it?

Example of df1:

```
   type - country 
0  001  - US      
1  002  - DE      
2  003  - ES     
3  004  - FR
```

Example of df2:

```
   Model
0  Clio
1  Q5  
2  RS6
3  AMG
```

Example of df3:

```
   Name
0  Richard
1  Paul
2  Juan
3  Del Castillo
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
df123 = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
```

The output is:

```
   type - country - Model - Name
0  001  - US      - NaN   - NaN
1  002  - DE      - NaN   - NaN
2  003  - ES      - NaN   - NaN 
3  004  - FR      - NaN   - NaN
```

Expected output:

```
   type - country- Model - Name
0  001  - US     - Clio  - Richard
1  002  - DE     - Q5    - Paul
2  003  - ES     - RS6   - Juan
3  004  - FR     - AMG   - Del Castillo
```

Comment: Try `pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)`?

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and the answers below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
out = df1.join([df2, df3])
```

Comment: This one looks great. Its the same as Roxy. Is this called a left join?

Comment: Yes, by pandas default its left join on dataframes indexes. Read the docs here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Type': ['001', '002'], 'country': ['US', 'DE']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Model': ['Clio', 'Q5']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Name': ['John', 'Mary']})

df = df1.join([df2, df3])

print(df)
```

The output would be:

```
  Type country Model  Name
0  001      US  Clio  John
1  002      DE    Q5  Mary
```